# How to call a Node.js package from Python

Tags: node.js, python-2.7

I have set up a little Python project that builds some docs and tests it with [Travis CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travis_CI).

Now I want to add an English linter to my project, but the ones I've found that seem interesting are in Node.js.

Is there a way to make calls to Node.js packages from a Python script? Or call an Node.js package from a Travis YAML file that's configured for Python?

Comment: You can do this with the built-in subprocess module.  Do you just need to run the node module, or run it and capture its output on the Python side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can call Node.js from Travis directly:

```
language: python
branches:
  only:
  - master
python:
  - '2.7'
before_install:
  - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/nvm.sh -O ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - nvm install 5 # For Node.js v5
  - node --version
install:
  - pip install -U pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - npm install ...
script:
  - make ...
  - call npm stuff here
```